# Drupal Views page URL problem

Tags: views, nodes

I've created page with Views, which is displaying gallery (image fields).

I've set the path to node/%/gallery.

Page is working when I access "http://example.com/node/9/gallery" but it doesn't work when I access it with alias "http://example.com/event/example-name/gallery"

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/60389/25879 and
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/70116/25879

Answer (score 0):

do not use node/%/.. as your path, this will disturb the default routing system.

> change the view's path to gallery/% or something.

if you want to keep this url, register a local task like here [How to add a local task tab to node view?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/93785/how-to-add-a-local-task-tab-to-node-view)

and in this page callback you can display the view with [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7),
 in this case you will remove the path of the view, or change it to a test-path.

but still, the alias with /gallery needs to be registered too !

Comment: I want the path to behave like this subpage of the node.

path-alias/gallery

Comment: then you need to setup this path alias yourself using [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) or [redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) or register in a custom module in [hoo_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)

Comment: updated the answer with a link for registering a local task